# NavController in ViewModel: androidx.navigation.NavController cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to inject `navController` into my ViewModel -

ViewModel -

```
@HiltViewModel
class DeviceHolderListViewModelImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val fetchUsersUseCase: FetchUsersUseCase,
    private val navigationUtil: NavigationUtil
    ) : DeviceHolderListViewModel, ViewModel() {
      

      // Trying to access navigationUtil here

}
```

NavigationUtil -

```
class NavigationUtil @Inject constructor(private val navController: NavController) {

    fun navigateTo(destination: String, bundle: Bundle) {

        when(destination) {
            DEVICE_HOLDER_LIST -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderListFragment, bundle)
            DEVICE_HOLDER_DETAILS -> navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderDetailsFragment, bundle)
        }
    }

    fun navigateBack() {
        navController.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

NavigationModule -

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object NavigationModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideNavController(activity: AppCompatActivity): NavController {
        return Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideNavigationUtil(navController: NavController): NavigationUtil {
        return NavigationUtil(navController)
    }
}
```

Upon trying to build the code, I get the following error -

> error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] androidx.navigation.NavController
> cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an
> @Provides-annotated method.

IS it because I am trying to access the `navController` from `ViewModel` while it should be accessed from a Fragment or Activity?

My aim is to initiate navigation from the ViewModel. How do I ideally do that?

---

EDIT: Changes according to @DAA's answer -

`NavigationUtil`

```
class NavigationUtil {

    private var navController: NavController? = null

    fun setController(controller: NavController) {
        navController = controller
    }

    fun clear() {
        navController = null
    }

    fun navigateTo(destination: String, bundle: Bundle) {

        when(destination) {
            DEVICE_HOLDER_LIST -> navController?.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderListFragment, bundle)
            DEVICE_HOLDER_DETAILS -> navController?.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderDetailsFragment, bundle)
        }
    }

    fun navigateBack() {
        navController?.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

`NavigationModule`

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object NavigationModule {

    @Provides
    @ViewModelScoped
    fun provideNavigationUtil(): NavigationUtil {
        return NavigationUtil()
    }
}
```

`NavigationUtil`

```
class NavigationUtil {

    private var navController: NavController? = null

    fun setController(controller: NavController) {
        navController = controller
    }

    fun clear() {
        navController = null
    }

    fun navigateTo(destination: String, bundle: Bundle) {

        when(destination) {
            DEVICE_HOLDER_LIST -> navController?.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderListFragment, bundle)
            DEVICE_HOLDER_DETAILS -> navController?.navigate(R.id.action_global_goto_deviceHolderDetailsFragment, bundle)
        }
    }

    fun navigateBack() {
        navController?.popBackStack()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest a different approach.

I usually make a `Navigatior` class, that is injected in both `Activity` and your `ViewModel`. `ViewModel` calls navigator methods and activity subscribes to them.

Disclaimer: Following code is written based on my memory and may not be syntactically correct. Feel free to improve it.

```
sealed interface NavEvent {
   data class Navigate(val directions: NavDirections): NavEvent
   object Pop(): NavEvent
   data class PopForResult(val requestKey: String, val result: Bundle): NavEvent
}
```

```
@Singleton
class Navigator @Inject constructor() {

   private val _navigateFlow = MutableSharedFlow<NavEvent>
   val navigateFlow: SharedFlow = _navigateFlow

   suspend fun navigate(nav: NavDirections) {
       _navigateFlow.emit(Navigate(directions))
   }
   
   suspend fun pop() {
       _navigateFlow.emit(Pop)
   }
}
```

```
@HiltViewModel
class MyVm @Inject constructor(
    private val navigator: Navigator
) : ViewModel() {

    fun onClickSmth() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            navigator.navigate(MyFragmentDirections.actionToSomewhere())
        }
    }
}
```

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : Activity {
    
    @Inject lateinit var navigator: Navigator

    private lateinit var navController: NavController = TODO()

    fun onCreate() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            navigator.navigateFlow.collect(this::onNavEvent)
        }
    }
    
    private fun onNavEvent(event: NavEvent) {
        when (navEvent) {
            Navigate -> navController.navigate(navEvent.directions)
            Pop -> navController.popBackStack()
            PopForResult -> {
                navController.previousBackStackEntry
                    ?.savedStateHandle
                    ?.set(event.requestKey, event.result)
                navController.popBackStack()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot inject directly the `NavController` with Hilt in that way, since you can only call `Navigation.findNavController` from your Activity/Fragment, but the `NavigationUtil` approach you are taking is a good one in order to have access to navigation from the ViewModel.

You only need to do a couple changes:

- Instead of having `NavController` passed as a parameter of `NavigationUtil`, create two methods `setNavController` and `clearNavController`.
- Make `NavigationUtil` scoped to the ViewModel annotating the provide method with `@ViewModelScoped`.
- Inject your `NavigationUtil` into your Activity, and call to `setNavController` in your `onCreate` method and to `clearNavController` in your `onDestroy` method.

Now your `NavigationUtil` has access to `NavController`, it is updated when the Activity is recreated (and cleared when it is destroyed), and you can access it from your ViewModel.

You can check the answer I gave to a very similar question here: [How to inject `rememberNavController` from jetpack compose into an activity using hilt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69276165/how-to-inject-remembernavcontroller-from-jetpack-compose-into-an-activity-usin/70855711#70855711)

Comment: How would the ViewModel have access to the `NavigationUtil`? Should I inject it in the `ViewModel` as well? Or pass it via a public function of the ViewModel?

Comment: Also, when trying to inject `NavigationUtil` in my fragment, I get a `NoSuchMethodException` upon the initialization of the fragment. I am posting the updated code in my question above.

Comment: You should inject it in both your Fragment/Activity and your ViewModel. The problem you are getting with the injection is due to using ViewModelScoped along with ActivityComponent. In Hilt, ViewModelScoped has to be used with ViewModelComponent. You could also use ApplicationComponent and Singleton. Check https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android#component-hierarchy

Comment: Thank you! I think you and @Peter are suggesting similar approaching wrt DI.